# MsBuild extension pack : how to use remote deployement for IIS6

Tags: msbuild, iis-6, msbuildextensionpack

In the documentation of the extension pack it is said for the target Iis6Website  :

Remote Execution Support: Yes. Please note that the machine you execute from must have IIS installed.

However it is not explained how to use it remotely.

Does anybody know the syntax to call it remotely ?

Comment: I've found the answer :  MachineName="$(DeploymentServerName)" UserName="$(RemoteUser)" UserPassword="$(RemotePassword)" could be used in every task

Comment: Where it should be used? just create property with this name?